# Convertir XML en UTF-8 a ISO-8859-1

Tags: java, xml, string, utf-8, conversión-de-tipos

Estoy desarrollando un servicio web que es invocado por una aplicación externa a la mía. En este servicio web recibo un XML con todos los parámetros necesarios para ofrecer el servicio. La cuestión es que el XML me llega con codificación UTF-8 y la base de datos donde almaceno la información está en Latin 1 (ISO-8859-1). ¿Cómo puedo hacer para convertir el XML a codificación Latin 1? Ya sea el XML completo o los atributos una vez extraídos. Tengo una clase Java que implementa el objeto que se recibe.

Ejemplo: Tengo el objeto `visita` y tiene un atributo que es `visita.getComentarioS()`. Para obtener el objeto desde el XML hago lo siguiente:

```
XmlVisita visita = (XmlVisita ) context.getParameter("xmlVisita");
```

donde context es un objeto de tipo `EventHandlerContext`. Al almacenar el comentario de la visita en la base de datos, si contiene caracteres especiales, se almacena mal ya que la base de datos está en Latin 1.

Comment: ¿El parámetro xmlVisita qué es: un string en formato xml? ¿Puedes intentar convertir el string de utf a iso antes de convertirlo en XmlVisita?

Comment: XmlVisita es una clase Java que implementa un objeto. Cuando hago context.getParameter("xmlVisita"), ese "xmlVisita" es para identificar en el XML que se recibe en la petición, a qué objeto se va a parsear. La cuestión es que no sé si antes de recoger el objeto desde la petición, se puede cambiar la codificación del XML en la petición.

Comment: Puedes ir cambiando los valores una vez los tengas en XmlVisita si antes no puedes

Comment: Eso estoy intentando hacer pero no funciona. En el objeto XmlVisita, los atributos son de tipo String y las soluciones que he probado pasan por la conversión a byte[]. El resultado final no es el que deseo.El ejemplo que tengo hecho ahora es:
byte[] cmntrsVst = new String(visitFromWeb.getComentariosVisita().getBytes(), "UTF-8").getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
System.out.println(new String(cmntrsVst));

Comment: Prueba a convertir así: new String(visitFromWeb.getComentariosVisita().getBytes("utf-8"), "iso-8859-1")

Comment: mira la respuesta editada, eso te deberia funcionar, ya editas tu la respuesta cuando lo pruebes, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Yo probaria con `XSLT`, para cambiar el encabezado a `encoding="ISO-8859-1"`:

```
<xsl:output encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>
```

No lo he probado pero seria algo asi, pruebalo y ya editas tu la respuesta:

```
TransFormerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Source xsl = new StreamSource("../doc.xsl");
Source xml = new StreamSource("../doc.xml");
Result salida = new StreamResult(new File("newDoc.xml"));
Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(xsl);
transformer.transform(xml,salida);
```

Saludos.